# Angular uib datepicker popup pagination causes overflow

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Angular uib datepicker, importing it with nocsss, and when I paginate, it briefly shows two calendars before resizing. I have tried adding `overflow: hidden` to the `table` in the date picker, but that causes the entire datepicker to be invisible. The green square is a temp button that shows and hides the datepicker. Why it is along side it is a separate issue.

[image: Broken datepicker]

my scss:

```
.datepicker-container {
    :global {
      button:not(.uib-title) {
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .uib-datepicker {
        //max-width: 238px;
        //overflow: hidden; -> this makes the entire datepicker invisible
        table {
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
      }

      .uib-right,
      .uib-left {
        height: 20px;
        background: $some-blue;
      }

      .uib-title {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .uib-day {
        padding: 0;
        transition: all 200ms linear;
        cursor: default;

        button {
          height: 24px;
          width: 100%;

          &:disabled {
            color: $some-grey;
            opacity: 0.75;
            cursor: not-allowed;
          }

          &.active {
            background: $some-blue;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: white;
          }
        }

        &:hover {
          color: $white;
          background: $some-blue;
        }
      }

      .text-center {
        text-align: center;
      }
```

While debugging it, I used the chrome debugger to break on subtree modification and it appears the problem is, of course, with the calendar's internals. It loads in the next month, *then* removes the nodes of the former month, which makes no sense, but fine. What that means is that for a brief moment, both months are visible. So if I do this, it *does* fix some of the issue:

```
          td {
            &:nth-of-type(8),
            &:nth-of-type(9),
            &:nth-of-type(10),
            &:nth-of-type(11),
            &:nth-of-type(12),
            &:nth-of-type(13),
            &:nth-of-type(14) {
              display: none;
            }
          }
```

Basically td's 1-7 are the next month, and 8-14 are the former month that angular shows briefly before removing. We can hide them like this, but this solution is brittle. If you rapidly click through the calendar, it flashes and expands just like in the example.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with the issue?

Comment: Or at least let the html from your component, and the @Component declaration.

Comment: Which library are you using anyway? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker OR https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples OR https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker ! And if you're using angularjs 1.x change tag of this Q. to angularjs instead of angular

Comment: Could you please try to remove `transition: all 200ms linear;` in your SCSS?